# awk and substitute semicolon (;) in appointed field

Tags: csv, awk, gsub

Can anybody explain me this small script.

```
echo -e "\"aa;bb\";cc ;\"dd ;ee\"; 
ff" | awk -v RS=\" -v ORS=\" 'NR%2==0{gsub(";",",")}
{print}'
```

In this script fields separated by (`;`), but if there is one or more `(;)` inside any field then this field is surrounded by `""`.It's `CSV-file`.

Therefore it is necessary to replace all `(;)` in this `fields` for further parsing.

Answer (score 2):

The echo prints two lines:

```
"aa;bb";cc ;"dd ;ee"; 
ff
```

And [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) splits records with each double quote, and in the even ones replace all semicolons with commas (`gsub`).

So, first record will be the content just before first double quote, it's a blank record but the important part is the condition `NR%2==0`. `NR` is one so the condition will be false, `gsub()` will not be executed, it will be printed with its `ORS` so output will be a double quote.

For second record content will be `aa;bb`, `NR%2==0` will be true and will replace the semicolon.

For third record content will be `;cc ;`, `NR%2==0` will be false and it will be printed.

And so on until end of file.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand why *"For second record content will be aa;bb, NR%2==0 will be true and will replace the semicolon."* and *"For third record content will be ;cc ;, NR%2==0 will be false and it will be printed."* is "TRUE" and "FALSE" respectively.

Comment: @Andry: Each double quote separates each record, and variable `NR` means number of records read. So `2 % 2 == 0` is true and `3 % 2 == 0` is false.

Comment: Thanks, friend. Now I understand everything.

Comment: If you so prof in awk can you get me some help in quotation single quotes inside awk expression. E.g. <code>awk 'BEGIN{RS="\"";ORS="\'"} $1'</code>. This does not work. I use sh as shell on FreeBSD.

Comment: @Andry: The example of your question does it fine. Escape them with backslashes. It's the same for a `BEGIN` block. It works for me so I don't know in what way it doesn't work for you.

Comment: My answer awk 'BEGIN{RS="\"";ORS="'\''"} $1' . May be it's safe some time for anybody. When you need use single quotes inside awk use pair single quotes as screen.

Comment: For me just ORS="\'" doesn not work. I use ORS="'\''". I have found right solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899001/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-awk-inside-printf (Kaz comment)