# how to delete duplicate lines in a text file in unix bash?

Tags: bash

I just have a file.txt with multiple lines, I would like to remove duplicate lines without sorting the file. what command can i use in unix bash ?

sample of file.txt

```
orangejuice;orange;juice_apple
pineapplejuice;pineapple;juice_pineapple
orangejuice;orange;juice_apple
```

sample of output:

```
orangejuice;orange;juice_apple
pineapplejuice;pineapple;juice_pineapple
```

Comment: I'd like to see this closed as duplicate, too, but I hope there is a better question to link to.

Comment: [Linux Bash commands to remove duplicates from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25393281/608639). Change the delimiter.

Answer (score 38):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file.txt
```

Comment: You can't write this to a file via an alias sourced from bashrc > output.txt it has only one line?

Comment: root@server:/tmp# alias RDL="awk '!a[\$0]++' cleanList.txt > cleanList2.txt"
bash: !a[\$0]++': event not found
root@server:/tmp# alias RDL="awk '\!a[$0]++' cleanList.txt > cleanList2.txt"
root@mdserver:/tmp# RDL
awk: cmd. line:1: \!a[bash]++
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ backslash not last character on line
root@server:/tmp# alias RDL="awk '\\!a[$0]++' cleanList.txt > cleanList2.txt"
???

Comment: Found this cat -n file_name | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157/unix-removing-duplicate-lines-without-sorting

Comment: better yet the `uniq` command works in an alias even http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html

Comment: @MasterJames: You'll need to single quote that expression, then escape the single quotes like: `alias RDL='awk '\''!a[$0]++'\'' cleanList.txt > cleanList2.txt'`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899594/751863. Alternatively, just use a function.

Comment: Thanks for that. Working! [as well... better]

Answer (score 14):

You can use Perl for this:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++' file.txt
```

The `-n` switch makes Perl process the file line by line. Each line (`$_`) is stored as a key in a hash named "seen", but since `++` happens after returning the value, the line is printed the first time it is met.

Comment: This in an alias when output to a file > output.txt creates an empty file?  alias RDL="perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++' cleanList.txt > cleanList2.txt"
root@server:/tmp# RDL
Can't modify anonymous hash ({}) in postincrement (++) at -e line 1, near "}++"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
root@server:/tmp#

Comment: Found this cat -n file_name | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157/unix-removing-duplicate-lines-without-sorting

Comment: the `uniq` command works in an alias even http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html

Comment: @MasterJames: The OP wanted to process the file "without sorting", which `uniq` can't do.

Comment: I see now uniq only removes repeat lines not dups from input. It only skips  whwn they'really the same on the next line (aka repeats not dups). This is fine for my situation, so i didn't notice that sort makes dups=repeats which uniq skips. Without sort dups that are non repeating are not removed. Thanks for clarity.