# Linux Bash commands to remove duplicates from a CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I will be combining a number of CSV files.  What I am trying to do is to:

1) Remove duplicate rows from the file, however, I need to check multiple columns as the criteria for what consists as a duplicate.  How do I do that?

2) It would be nice to then create a 2nd output file to see what was removed in case something was removed that was not supposed to be removed.

3) Create a list of items as an input file to run as a (if this row contains this word in a this particular column, then remove the entire row.

If someone could help me with the commands to do this, that would be great! Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Here is a sample of what the data looks like (here is an example as suggested):

I have a csv file like this :

```
column1    column2

john       kerry
adam       stephenson
ashley     hudson
john       kerry
etc..
```

I want to remove duplicates from this file, to get only for the question at 1:

```
column1    column2

john       kerry
adam       stephenson
ashley     hudson
```

For question 3, I want to take the 2nd list...meaning the output of the 1st list and scrub this futher.  I want a file like input.txt that contains:

```
adam
```

Then, the final output will be:

```
column1    column2

john       kerry
ashley     hudson
```

So, the input.txt file in the example contains the word adam (this way I can make a long list of words to check in the input.txt file).  For #3, I need a code snipet that will check column 1 of all lines of the CSV for all the words input file, then remove any matches from the csv.

Comment: Perl and awk are well-suited for this kind of work. You will probably get better answers if you provide an example input file and show what you've already tried.

Comment: Just added.  I know nothing about Perl or Awk, but I do know Bash.  I hope someone can give me Bash commands.

Comment: Just to make sure: you check _some_ columns for equality, which means _some_ columns may differ but are still counted as equal (in other words: `uniq` does not work)?

Comment: I agree with tkocmathla... You might want to do this using something more suited than bash for this kind of work. And i'd like to add python to the list.

Comment: I would take your csv file and put it into an sqlite database or something. If you're trying to compare equality based on some combination of columns, you're going to find that VERY hard in bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide more details for question 3, but for question 1 and 2 the following `awk` one-liner will work.

```
awk 'seen[$0]++{print $0 > "dups.csv"; next}{print $0 > "new.csv"}' mycsv
```

And with some whitespace added for clarity:

```
awk 'seen[$0]++ {
  print $0 > "dups.csv"; next
}
{
  print $0 > "new.csv"
}' mycsv
```

This will not print anything to STDOUT but will create two files. `dups.csv` will contain all the duplicates (that is if there are 5 entries of same line, this file will contain 4 entries that were removed as dups) that were removed and `new.csv` will contain all unique rows.

`seen[$0]++` is a test we do for each line. If the line is present in our array it will be inserted to `dups.csv` file and we will move to the next line using `next`. If line is not present we will add that line to the array and write it to `new.csv` file.

Use of `$0` means entire line. If you want to specify fewer columns, you can do so. You just need to set the input field separator based on delimiter. You have mentioned `csv` but I don't see any `comma` delimiters so I am using the default separator which is `[[:space:]]+`.

*Also, it is comma separated, I was just putting sample data up. So, if I want to use the above example but want to test only columns 3 & 4 (using the seen command), how would I do that in a comma separated file?*

For true `csv` just set the field separator to `,`. `seen` is not a command. It is a hash that retains column as keys. So you will modify the above command to:

```
awk -F, 'seen[$3,$4]++{print $0 > "dups.csv"; next}{print $0 > "new.csv"}' mycsv
```

**Update:**

Once you have a list without dups using the commands stated above. We are left with:

```
$ cat new.csv 
john,kerry
adam,stephenson
ashley,hudson
```

```
$ cat remove.txt 
adam
```

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{remove[$1]++;next}!($1 in remove)' remove.txt new.csv 
john,kerry
ashley,hudson
```

Comment: The default separator is `[[:space:]]+`, isn't it?

Comment: @TomFenech Yea, was intending on writing sequences of `[:space:]` but `[[:space:]]+` is shorter. Will update, thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  I just updated for question 3.  Also, it is comma separated, I was just putting sample data up.  So, if I want to use the above example but want to test only columns 3 & 4 (using the seen command), how would I do that in a comma separated file?

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior Not sure if I follow. Whats the algorithm to create a file that just contains `adam`? Will update the post to answer your other question.

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior Thanks but you still haven't mentioned why the list will only contain `adam` and not `john` or `ashley`?

Comment: @jaypal Because the input file is to remove certain names from the csv.  So, I only want all people named adam removed.  I want all people with other names to stay on this list.  I hope this makes sense.  Also, some of the names on the list have 2 names like "Donna Rae", "Betty Sue", etc.  Would there be any special case to handle that?

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior If you have that list ready then it is easy to remove from the main file. I understand that list will contain names that needs to be removed from the main file but if you want to create that list from a given file, you need to tell me how to wish to populate it in the first place. For eg. why only `adam` makes it to that list and not other names.

Comment: @jaypal I will be manually making the list of names.  This was just sample data, to give an idea, so I didn't have to deal with lots of columns.  But the main data will be of business names.  Some businesses we want off the list.  So, I just want to have a remove list, that has the business name (in column 1 for example) & then remove the entire line from the csv.  Does that help?

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior Yes that helps, thanks. Have updated the answer to show how you can use a list of names as reference to remove lines from your csv file.

Comment: To remove rows with duplicated email addresses case insensitive in column 1 of a csv try:
awk -F';' 'seen[tolower($1)]++{print $0 > "customers_dups.csv"; next}{print $0 > "customers_new.csv"}' customers.csv