# Get comma separated distinct values in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a unix file Err_Call_sipregtracking.csv as follows

```
colnum~filename~date~fieldnum~name~value
15~YYYYMMDD_BDACA_SELFRELATIVE_ARN~30MAR2016:00:00:00~1~BDA_CA_Code~1
15~YYYYMMDD_BDACA_SELFRELATIVE_ARN~30MAR2016:00:00:00~2~ARN_Code~2
15~YYYYMMDD_BDACA_SELFRELATIVE_ARN~30MAR2016:00:00:00~544~ALL~0
15~YYYYMMDD_BDACA_SELFRELATIVE_ARN~30MAR2016:00:00:00~544~ALL~0
```

Here delimeter is `~`.
I want distinct values of name column into a variable

My required output is:

```
'BDA_CA_Code','ARN_Code','ALL'
```

Please help me to achieve this.I tried with this

```
cat Err_Call_sipregtracking.csv | awk -F'~' '{print $5}' | uniq
```

Output is:

```
name
BDA_CA_Code
ARN_Code
ALL
```

But i don't want header in the result and I also want them in quotes and comma separated.

Comment: note `cat file | awk 'things'` is not necessary. `awk 'things' file` suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not very optimized but works:

```
tail -n+2 Newfile.csv | awk -F'~' '{$5="\""$5"\""; print $5}' | uniq | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/\,$/\n/'
```

If you want single quotes instead:

```
tail -n+2 Newfile.csv | awk -F'~' '{a = "'"'"'"; print a $5 a}' | uniq | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/\,$/\n/'
```

Explanation:

- `tail -n+2 Newfile.csv` omits the first line
- `awk -F'~' '{$5="\""$5"\""; print $5}'` extracts the 5th column and surrounds it with quotes (for the single quotes, notice how unnecessarily complicated the quote printing is, there might be a way around this)
- `uniq` removes duplicates
- `tr '\n' ','` replaces newlines with commas
- `sed 's/\,$/\n/'` removes the final comma and replaces it with a newline (for output readability)

Comment: it is interesting; however, note that `awk` can handle much of this internally. In general, piping so many commands is not considered good practice since it involves more CPU time.

Comment: That is true; I have however found that piping is however easier to explain step by step; besides, those commands extend far outside the range of `awk` and text processing, and for most usages, the CPU shouldn't be much of an issue here. That said, I understand your point.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is a matter of balance and, in fact, good thing of little commands is _one doing just one thing_. My current answer is a bit over-complicated since I wanted to just use `awk`. However, in your answer the first pipe, for example, could be removed by a simple `NR>1`, as well as `uniq` by placing items in an array.

Comment: The statement `those commands extend far outside the range of awk and text processing` is wrong. The commands needed for this are perfectly mundane for text processing and used regularly in awk.

Answer (score 5):

The key here is to store the values in an array, so you then print all the elements:

```
$ awk -F'~' 'NR>1{item[$5]} END {for (i in item) print i}' file
ARN_Code
BDA_CA_Code
ALL
```

Note the usage of `NR>1` to skip the header.

Then, you can print the elements wrapped with single quotes with `printf "\047%s\047\n", i`, since `print "\047hello\047"` prints `'hello'`:

```
$ awk -F'~' 'NR>1{item[$5]} END {for (i in item) printf "\047%s\047\n", i}' file
'ARN_Code'
'BDA_CA_Code'
'ALL'
```

To join these into a comma-separated list of items, just print a comma before every item starting from the second one ([credits to Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654568/get-comma-separated-distinct-values-in-unix/38654741#comment64702213_38654741)):

```
for (i in item) printf "%s\047%s\047", (++c>1 ? "," : ""), i
print ""
```

See it in action:

```
$ awk -F'~' 'NR>1{item[$5]} END {for (i in item) printf "%s\047%s\047", (++c>1 ? "," : ""), i; print ""}' file
'ARN_Code','BDA_CA_Code','ALL'
```

Comment: @sjsam how? I cannot see it.

Comment: You've probably gone through my answer, but I feel the single for-loop is more readable here. and time saving. And a ++ for addressing the issue

Comment: @sjsam ah right, now I understand: instead of storing all the items in an array, you keep printing them as soon as you see them. This is also interesting, yes.

Comment: @sjsam ...It works like a charm.Thanks a lot.i tried it without loop  as ........ sort | uniq | xargs | sed -e 's/ /","/g' | sed "s/\"/'/g" | sed -e "s/.*/'&'/")  ...... Can you please suggest if this is faster than looping or not

Comment: @fedorqui btw, I may be wrong with my previous assessment that `{item[$5]}`in your case is better than `$5 in field` which I used, both have the same complexity for `n` lines. haven't they?  In your case the index can be added only after checking if it already exists.

Comment: @PavaniSrujana : You mean to thank \@fedorqui. :) Both approaches do the same thing. And if I understand correctly both have the same the same complexity. But I prefer this solution to my (more idiomatic, or is it?) approach as it easily conveys the idea.

Comment: @sjsam well, this is quite relative: my approach focuses on fetching the data and then printing it later on; yours does all in one shot. Also mine uses some tweaks to prevent using Bash later on to strip the trailing comma. But, as they say, everyone to his own taste : )

Comment: @fedorqui--Thanks a lot

Comment: That's a very reasonable approach with the caveats being memory usage and order of the output, but FWIW I'd write the END section as `awk -F'~' 'NR>1{item[$5]} END{for (i in item) printf "%s\047%s\047", (++c>1 ? "," : ""), i; print ""}' file`. IMHO `print "'\''" i "'\''"` is clearer written as `print "\047" i "\047"` btw.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the explanations. Yes, `print "'\''"` seems like too much. [I see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12845216/1983854) that also `\x27` does it.

Comment: You should always use octal, not hex, escape codes - see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Comment: @EdMorton immediately favorited that page. The `awk 'BEGIN{print "\x27foo!\x27"}'` was clear enough : )

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is your friend:

```
$ var=$(awk  -v FS="~" 'NR>1 && !($5 in field){printf "\047%s\047,",$5;field[$5]}' Err_Call_sipregtracking.csv)
$ var="${var%,}" #Stripping the trailing comma
$ echo "$var"
'BDA_CA_Code','ARN_Code','ALL'
```

**Notes**

- I have used the octal `\047` for single quote as suggested by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)  in his comment. See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38655597/revisions).
- Also check [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in the GNU documentation.

Comment: I like how you use `-vq="'"` to print those single quotes. It looks easier to read.

Comment: @fedoroqui-- I am new to unix.This worked fine but i couldnot undersatnd how it is achieved.Could you please explain what is inside that printf statement

Comment: 1) Not leaving a space between `-v` and the variable name makes the script unnecessarily gawk-specific. 2) The idiomatic way to test for uniquness is an array named/populated as `!seen[$5]++`. 3) Without a terminating newline the output is not text per POSIX and so invites undefined behavior from any tool parsing it afterwards. 4) Don't add things then take them away again (e.g. the comma) as it's error prone. 5) You don't need to do shell operations to change awk output, just keep it in awk. 6) To get a single quote in an awk script use the octal `\047` - far less headaches than a variable.

Comment: @fedorqui use of a variable for `'` makes it harder to write your scripts ingeneral. For example to find `'foo.bar'` would be `$0 ~ (q "foo\\.bar" q)` vs `/\047foo\.bar\047/`. Note the necessary extra escape in the first one plus the need to explicitly prepend with `$0 ~` and it's using string concatenation which is slow.

Comment: @EdMorton : Thankyou and enlightened.!! Regarding point 3 did you mean terminating null character, I may do `END{printf ""}` then?

Comment: You're welcome. Not a null character (`\0`), a newline (`\n` or, much less commonly for UNIX applications, `\r\n`). `printf ""` would produce neither of those, but `print ""` will produce the appropriate newline (as set in `ORS`). I just make the point that a newline might be `\n` or `\r\n` to show why you should use `print ""` (which uses the current/appropriate `ORS` setting) rather than hard-coding what you THINK a newline should be with `printf "\n"` in case you were considering doing that.

Comment: @EdMorton : Is this still necessary,  if you're storing the result to a variable like I did? Also, if time permits, pls give me a link to the posix article on this.

Comment: To be honest, idk if a POSIX shell is required to be able to handle setting a variable from input that doesn't contain a terminating newline. I suspect not since per POSIX a line is "A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters **plus a terminating <newline> character**." but idk. The POSIX article is just the spec, see the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'~' 'NR>1 && !seen[$5]++{printf "%s\047%s\047", (NR>2 ? "," : ""), $5} END{print ""}' file
'BDA_CA_Code','ARN_Code','ALL'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first line with `sed 1d`, get the 5th field with `cut` and use `printf` for marmatting the unique sorted results:

```
printf "'%s'\n" $(sed 1d Err_Call_sipregtracking.csv | cut -d~ -f5 | sort -u)
```

This doesn't fulfill your request to get it as a single line:

```
printf "'%s'," $(sed 1d Err_Call_sipregtracking.csv | cut -d~ -f5 | sort -u)|sed 's/,$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct but modify it a bit , like below:

`cat Err_Call_sipregtracking| awk -F'~' '{print $5}' | uniq|sed 1d | sed -n -e 'H;${x;s/\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;}'`