# Field separation with adding quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am beginner in shell script . 
I have one variable containing value having = character. 
I want to add quote in fields after = Character.

```
abc="source=TDG"
echo $abc|awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

My code is printing one field only. 
my expected output is

```
source='TDG'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ abc='source=TDG'
$ echo "$abc" | sed 's/[^=]*$/\x27&\x27/'
source='TDG'
```

- `[^=]*$` match non `=` characters at end of line
- `\x27&\x27` add single quotes around the matched text

With `awk`

```
$ echo "$abc" | awk -F= '{print $1 FS "\047" $2 "\047"}'
source='TDG'
```

- `-F=` input field separator is `=`
- `print $1 FS "\047" $2 "\047"` print first field, followed by input field separator, followed by single quotes then second field and another single quotes
- See [how to escape single quote in awk inside printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899001/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-awk-inside-printf)
   for more ways of handling single quotes in print

With [bash parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ echo "${abc%=*}='${abc#*=}'"
source='TDG'
```

- `${abc%=*}` will delete last occurrence of `=` and zero or more characters after it
- `${abc#*=}` will delete zero or more characters and first `=` from start of string

Comment: Swap your use of quotes in sed so you can avoid those ugly hex codes: `" ' ' "`

Comment: @Harvey while it would work in this case, one needs to be careful using double quotes as it will be interpreted by shell before getting passed to sed

Answer (score 3):

Sed would be the better choice:

```
echo "$abc" | sed "s/[^=]*$/'&'/"
```

Awk can do it but needs extra bits:

```
echo "$abc" | awk -F= 'gsub(/(^|$)/,"\047",$2)' OFS==
```

Answer (score 0):

```
What is taking place?
```

Using sub to surround TDG with single quotes by its octal nr to avoid quoting problems.

```
echo "$abc" | awk '{sub(/TDG/,"\047TDG\047")}1'
source='TDG'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.