# Single quotes in awk's system

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to run bioawk ([an extension of awk for fasta files](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk)) from awk's system functionality:

```
awk -v var=$i '{system("~/bin/bioawk-master/bioawk -c fastx '\''{if ($name==\""var"\"){print \">\"$name\"\\\\n\"$seq}}'\'' ../../prokka/"$2"/"$1"/"$1".ffn")}'
```

The result prints the literal "\n" between the values of $name and $seq instead of the intended carriage return.

What it prints:

```
NAME\nSEQUENCE
```

What I would like it to print:

```
NAME
SEQUENCE
```

When I print the bioawk command that want to run with:

```
awk -v var=$i '{system("echo ~/bin/bioawk-master/bioawk -c fastx '\''{if ($name==\""var"\"){print \">\"$name\"\\\\n\"$seq}}'\'' ../../prokka/"$2"/"$1"/"$1".ffn")}'
```

I get:

```
~/bin/bioawk-master/bioawk -c fastx {if ($name=="CANHHJNM_03494"){print ">"$name"\n"$seq}} ../../prokka/p190631-dr-tm-dc-sp-pi/EP41/EP41.ffn
```

I can see that it is missing the single quotes surrounding the brackets. I though having `'\''` would [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899001/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-inside-awk) this issue, but obviously it doesn't. Any help with this problem would be much appreciated

Comment: why are you running `bioawk` within `awk`?

Comment: I have a text file with data I'd like to use as input for bioawk. Awk parses a metadata file and bioawk parses a fasta file

Comment: messing with nested `\\\\\\s` is always a headache, unless it is your fulltime job to master such arcana ;-). I would try `\\\n` and even `\\n` as well. Good luck.

Comment: @JulioDiaz in terms of layers of calls, it's much more likely you should do `shell { awk; bioawk }` than `shell { awk { system { shell { bioawk } } } }`. If you [edit] your question to show us concise, testable sample input and expected output then I expect someone can help you figure out how to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 2):

not sure this will solve your problem but the (second) easiest way to handle single quotes in an `awk` script is defining it externally as a variable

```
$ awk -v q="'" 'BEGIN{print q "single_quoted" q}'

'single_quoted'
```

Comment: IMHO the easiest way is to use `\047` wherever you want `'` since you can do `print "\047single_quoted\047"` or `/\047single_quoted\047/` so no changes based on context and it'll work with no changes whether the script is stored in a file or called on the command line.

Comment: i'll do a tiny append to Ed's answer. as a generic approach, for any valid awk string, if the item that needs to shell-quoted also has single-quotes inside it, first do gsub(/\047/, "\047\134\047\047", item_to_be_quoted), which is equivalent to changing each instance of single-quote to ' \ ' ' .  Afterwards, pad single-quote (\047) to both ends, as Ed has suggested. Those octal quotes look absolutely hideous, but it's a clean approach instead of dealing with the plethora of back-slash and quotation caveats and nuisances.