# why escaping single quote inside awk is not working

Tags: bash, quotes

Hi there i am trying to understand why the following does not work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "it\'s my life" }'
```

I know that as soon as the first single quote opens before BEGIN, then it searches for a closing single quote that in general it finds it after }. However in my example i want to print somethin with another single quote in it. Because it is going to interrupt the SHELL'S opening and closing of the first and last single quotes, i need to do something, so i escape it and it doesnn't work. I saw this answer
[How to escape a single quote inside awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899001/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-inside-awk) but i didn't undertand why. Thanks.

Comment: Because the shell doesn't support escaping inside single quotes.

Comment: But note that `bash` does provide a nice mechanism: `awk $'BEGIN{ print "it\'s my life" }'`  Just precede the opening `'` with `$` to enable the escaping you want.

Comment: @WilliamPursell But you have to be careful, because then it will expand escape sequences like `\n`, which should normally be passed literally to `awk`, so you have to write `\\n`

Comment: @WilliamPursell You could post that as an answer at the linked question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, i got it!!

Comment: @Barmar I would consider posting that as an answer there except that a) that question does not have a bash tag and b) this style of quoting is an abomination!

Comment: What didn't you understand about the answers to the question you link to?

Comment: @john notice that `awk` is not relevant here: `echo 'BEGIN{ print "it\'s my life" }'` (this statement does the same)

Answer (score 0):

My two preferred options:

#### ⒈ Use double quotes for the enclosure

```
awk "BEGIN{ print 'it\'s my life' }"
```

#### ⒉ Use a heredoc

```
awk <<-DONE
BEGIN{
    print "it's my life"
}
DONE
```